# Is it possible to extend Django admin with views not related to the database tables content?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I work on a simple app with two basic models, Document and Word. The user uploads a document, and each word from the Document is extracted in a Word entry. The user should be able to view, add, edit and remove the documents and the words, so I thought it would be good to use Django admin. But also the user should be able to do something more with the words, usually in a group of two and some additional adjustable parameters (like calculating Dice similarity). 
Is there a way I can do all this in a one-level application? Or I have to make every user admin user, and make an app with just the additional functionality?

Comment: you can extend the built in Admin to do this; look at supplying a custom ModelForm with the extra parameters and functions on submit to deal with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [custom view in the ModelAdmin](http://contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) or even [in the admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites) so there is no need to create an additional app.